# SQL SUM Same columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [ArticleId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [Type] [smallint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Inside this table i have some results which looks like this

```
ArticleId     Quantity     Type
------------- ------------ ------
10               50          1
12               20          1
10               10          1
10               18          1
12                5          2
17               14          2
10               30          2
```

- Type 1 means that article is planned for production
- Type 2 means that article is completed

I need output query which shows me list of all articles

Output = Planed - Completed

**Example**: ArticleId:10 Planned quantity is: 78 Completed quantity is:

30 Output = 78 - 30 = **48**

I really don't have anything to show. I only know i need to group by `ArticleId`.

I tried like this

```
SELECT
    articleid,
    SUM(quantity) - (SELECT SUM(quantity)
                     FROM stackoverflow
                     WHERE type = 2
                       AND main.articleId = stackoverflow.articleId
                     GROUP BY articleid)
FROM 
    stackoverflow AS main
WHERE 
    type = 1
GROUP BY 
    articleid
```

Comment: Your table definition looks like SQL Server, so I changed the tag accordingly.

Comment: @MageeWorld just hit edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use case and sum

```
select ArticleId , sum( case type 
                       when 1 then Quantity
                       when 2 then -Quantity
                     end) Output 
from stackoverflow  
group by ArticleId
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to substract aggregated sums of both types:

```
SELECT
  [ArticleId],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN [Quantity] ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN [Quantity] ELSE 0 END) AS [PlannedSubQuantityTotal]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow]
GROUP BY [ArticleId]
```

Or use a "trick" with summing completed together with planned with a `-` prefix:

```
SELECT
  [ArticleId],
  SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN [Quantity] WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN -[Quantity] ELSE 0 END) AS [PlannedSubQuantityTotal]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow]
GROUP BY [ArticleId]
```